Read only from one channel of the ADC
I'm using STM32CubeIDE and I have two active ADCs with many channels reading, some in regular converison, some injected, etc.
The entire project is autogenerated from stm32 MC Workbench but I added a channel 11 for an external potentiometer.
I don't really know in the autogenerated files where the other ADC channels are read, and in addition to reading those channels, I should also read channel 11.
What I usually do is to read in the *HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback *all channels with an "array[channel]" and then choose the one that I am interested in. But I think I can't do that because in the autogenerated code the other channels are already read somewhere, so I would like something specific only for the 11th channel.
I ask you if this code is sufficient (in the main.c) to read also from ADC1 and channel 11:

I problemi sono due:

there is the error: ADC_HandleTypeDef has no member named rank

I can't insert a breakpoint inside HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback a causa dell'errore "Failed to insert all hardware breakpoints: You may have requested too many hardware breakpoints/watchpoints" .. this does not allow me to understand if the code actually enters the callback during debugging or not (obviously I only have one project open and only that breakpoint)






if (hadc->Rank == 4), Rank is a configuration parameter when you initialize an ADC channel, not part of ADC_HandleTypeDef. 2)I don't know what you are trying to accomplish. In scan mode, the channels assigned to higher ranks will be scanned in higher priority. If CH3 is assigned as rank 1, CH1 to rank 2, and CH11 to rank 3 (as per what shown on your CubeMx configuration). Scan order will be CH3, CH1 and CH11. You are the one that set CH11 to rank 3, and you can always change whatever scanning order you want or read the ADC on demand without the scan mode.


@hcheung 1) Exactly, they are two different structs so it gives me error. 2) I should create an array[x] long x (x = number of channels to read), a loop in the callback that reads all the channels and pass to another variable only the one array[my_channel] of my interest?
